# Rake doesn't create Mailer Templates when running RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rake

In our project we have `rake` task, that creates mailer templates in database. 
While running all `specs`, some of them are failing saying that the db record for some mailers don't exist.
Any ideas on what could be the reason for this and how to fix it?

Here the example of the task to create Mailer template.

```
desc "Creates mailer templates"
task create_mailers: :environment do

  MailerTemplate.delete_all

  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    MailerTemplate.create(locale: locale, mailer: "info#action", content: %{<p>Content</p>})
  end
end
```

This is my database_cleaner.rb file

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion)
    Rake::Task["create_mailers"].invoke
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = example.metadata[:js] ? :deletion: :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run
    end
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    Capybara.reset_sessions!
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: And why would you expect that rake task to run when running specs?

Comment: @BroiSatse I've updated post.